# Is there a way to allow only one thread to use a socket?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets

I am currently working with an HSM on a program in which I have a multithread client-server application using sockets.

This is how it works:
The main thread of the server waits and accepts N clients, each time a new request from a client arrives, a new thread is created, in which the client has to authenticate itself (using a login) and then a new socket is binded to that communication.

Due to security specification, I need that only authenticated clients can communicate with the server, and I supposed this scenario:
A client `client1` authenticate itself, and a new socket is binded (e.g. id=1234). Another client `client2` **not authenticated** sees that `client1` is using socket 1234, and so `client2` starts using socket 1234 to communicate with the server, even if it is not authenticated.

Could this scenario happen?
If it could, my idea was to allow in some way a socket to be used only once, in this way only the first client connected to it (the authenticated one) can use it. Is there a way to do something like this? Should I consider other ideas?

Comment: Socket descriptors should be unique per process. In the POSIX world (e.g. Linux and macOS) descriptors are basically indexes into a process-specific array.

Comment: What do you call `id`? A file-descriptor? A port-number?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude thank you, so there is no way in which a process can access the array related to other processes?

Comment: What kind of socket? With a datagram socket, you could have a problem, but a TCP socket requires matching IP addresses and ports. This makes things harder, [but not impossible.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address_spoofing) You're probably headed in [the direction of TLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security) to make things even harder still on a potential attacker.

Comment: @prog-fh the socket descriptor

Comment: @user4581301 a TCP socket. And also I'm working locally since I'm using a HSM so clients and server will be process working on the same machine

Comment: On a system like Windows, Linux or macOS (and more), processes are separate entities with separate and distinct memory maps.

Comment: That reduces some of the complications since you can reject everything from off the computer, and presumably the folks you give access to the computer are trustworthy. Yeah, that never goes wrong. Anyway, how much potential malice are you willing to accept or ignore? If someone doesn't go out of their way to break the system, a socket cannot talk to a socket it hasn't formally connected to, and TCP is a one-to-one connection so you can't have two clients connected to the same socket.

Comment: @AndreaRubi: The only way to use a socket (or any handle) belonging to another process is either (a) inherit it or (b) the `DuplicateHandle` (for sockets `WSADuplicateSocket`) API.  If you don't give the `PROCESS_DUP_HANDLE` right to the attacker, they can't do this.

Comment: "*Another client `client2` **not authenticated** sees that `client1` is using socket 1234*" - and how do you suppose it would be able to see that exactly? "*and so `client2` starts using socket 1234 to communicate with the server*" - that is not how sockets work. One process can't just hijack another process's sockets like that. "*Could this scenario happen?*" - no

Comment: Thank you to everyone, you all were very helpful.